# Compare methods of notifying about changes from services to controllers AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have found this solution from Aviv Ben-Yosef in his [blog post](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/04/angularjs-notifying-about-changes-from-services-to-controllers/):

```
angular.module('app').controller('TheCtrl', function($scope, NotifyingService) {
    // ... stuff ...
    NotifyingService.subscribe($scope, function somethingChanged() {
        // Handle notification
    });
});

angular.module('app').factory('NotifyingService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        subscribe: function(scope, callback) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on('notifying-service-event', callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },

        notify: function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event');
        }
    };
});
```

I am thinking to do this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandon7810/msjkv72r/75/)

```
angular.module('app').factory('NotifyingService', function() {

    var handlers = {
        list: []
    };

    return {
        subscribe: function(callback) {
            handlers.list.push(callback)
        },

        notify: function() {
            handlers.list.forEach(function(handler) {
                handler();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Edited: My goal is send changes to controllers in the same page. For example, there is a controller is doing something with the user and then it will notify the results to other controllers on the same page every time. I don't need to have the following abilities: unsubscribe the handlers, differentiate which handler to fire each time.

My solution seems very simple and I have not found anyone using it on internet, so I am feeling there should be something wrong with it (memory issues?).

Please point out the flaws in my solution (with resources if complicated. Ex. Memory). All I want to know is if this solution is okay to go with.

If my solution is good, please tell me, or compare pros and cons of both solutions.

---

### Updated

Thanks to @Daniel Beck. He pointed out that my solution does need a way/function to remove handler once the controllers are out of scopes, otherwise memory leaks. I believe this is the major flaw in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious -- I'm sure someone will come along to point that out if so -- but it seems to me that the sole advantage to the first one (from the blog post) is that you don't have to remember to destroy the `$on` watcher when you're done with it.  Its major disadvantage is that the service uses a single event name for all its `$emit`s -- if you used this service in two different controllers, both would be triggered every time; there's no way to differentiate which handler you actually intended to trigger.

Your version shares that flaw, and additionally provides no way to remove unneeded handlers -- it appears to support only running each of a list of callbacks when its `notify` is called. Which is exactly what `$rootScope.$emit` does already.

I think you're both kinda reinventing the wheel, here.

Comment: But you do need to be able to unsubscribe the handlers when those controllers go out of scope, otherwise memory leak.  The single handler thing -- ok, if that's all you need, but it's still just a more limited version of what already exists in $emit.

Comment: Great. This is what I want to know.

Comment: @DanielBeck what is the standard established way to do this?

Comment: $emit or $broadcast to pass around discrete events; or else just $watch the data in a service to be notified when it changes.